# Next.js with custom express server re-renders all custom routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

I've set up a custom express server in server.js like the docs for Next.js give an [example of](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js), however, every time I navigate to any dynamic routes defined there, there is a re-render of the app, including the  which contains my styles causing a pretty bad flash of unstyled content. Is there a way to ensure the dynamic routes do not trigger a re-render?

Here is my server.js file:

```js
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
    .prepare()
    .then(() => {
        const server = express();

        server.get("/press/:slug", (req, res) => {
            const actualPage = "/press";
            const queryParams = { slug: req.params.slug, apiRoute: "press" };
            return app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
        });

        server.get("/locations/:slug", (req, res) => {
            const actualPage = "/locations/location";
            const queryParams = { slug: req.params.slug, apiRoute: "location" };
            return app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
        });

        server.get("/insights/:slug", (req, res) => {
            const actualPage = "/insights/insight";
            const queryParams = { slug: req.params.slug, apiRoute: "insight" };
            return app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
        });

        // server.get("/_preview/:id/:wpnonce", (req, res) => {
        //     const actualPage = "/preview";
        //     const queryParams = { id: req.params.id, wpnonce: req.params.wpnonce };
        //     app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
        // });

        const robotsOptions = {
            root: __dirname + '/static/',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
            }
        };
        server.get('/robots.txt', (req, res) => (
            res.status(200).sendFile('robots.txt', robotsOptions)
        ));

        const sitemapOptions = {
            root: __dirname + '/static/',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
            }
        };
        server.get('/sitemap.xml', (req, res) => (
            res.status(200).sendFile('sitemap.xml', sitemapOptions)
        ));

        server.get("*", (req, res) => {
            return handle(req, res);
        });

        server.listen(3000, err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3000");
        });
    })
    .catch(ex => {
        console.error(ex.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Comment: Are you using the Next router link or normal links? Any standard link will force a reload, while the Next router link will resolve on the client.

Comment: Using the <Link> component provided by Next.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how you're using your Link? I've seen this issue caused by improper use of Link many many times.

Comment: <Link prefetch href={`/insights/${this.state.posts[key].fields.slug}`}>
                                    <a className="btn btn_orange read_more">Read More</a>
                                </Link>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your href should the as attribute. rebuild your href attribute according the docs

take a look on nextjs documentation
https://nextjs.org/docs#with-link